# Why do I need to pin a future before I can await a reference to it?

Tags: rust, async-await, future

The [tokio tutorial for `select!`](https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial/select) states:

> The thing to note is that, to .await a reference, the value being referenced must be pinned or implement Unpin.

Indeed, the following code fails to compile:

```rs
let fut = example(); // example is an async fn
(&mut fut).await;
```

With the following error message:

```
error[E0277]: `from_generator::GenFuture<[static generator@src/main.rs:15:27: 17:2]>` cannot be unpinned
... snip ...
within `impl futures::Future<Output = i32>`, the trait `Unpin` is not implemented for `from_generator::GenFuture<[static generator@src/main.rs:15:27: 17:2]>
... snip ...
note: consider using `Box::pin`
```

Pinning the future solves the problem:

```rs
let fut = example(); // example is an async fn
tokio::pin!(fut);
(&mut fut).await;
```

Why is it necessary to pin the future in order to await a reference to it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.await` generates code that invokes [`Future::poll`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/future/trait.Future.html#tymethod.poll). The first parameter has type `Pin<&mut Self>`. The main characteristic of `Pin<P>` is that it represents a pointer to a value that is guaranteed to never move after the `Pin<P>` is created, unless the pointee implements `Unpin` (which means it doesn't care if it's moved).

Let's first answer: Why is it *not* necessary to pin a future in order to await it by value? That is, why does this work:

```
pub async fn foo() {
    let fut = async {};
    fut.await;
}
```

It's simple: `fut.await` consumes `fut`.

```
pub async fn foo() {
    let fut = async {};
    fut.await;
    drop(fut); // error[E0382]: use of moved value: `fut`
}
```

There is no opportunity for us to move `fut` after `fut.await`, so there is no way we could violate `Pin`'s rules on `fut`.

However, if we could `.await` a reference, then we *would* be able to move the original value after the `.await`, and that would be disastrous if `fut` was self-referential.

The error comes from the compiler failing to find an implementation of `Future` for the expression `&mut fut`. There is [`impl<'_, F> Future for &'_ mut F where F: Future + Unpin + ?Sized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/future/trait.Future.html#impl-Future) in the standard library; however, `fut` doesn't implement `Unpin`, so that's what the compiler reports in its error message.

`tokio::pin!(fut)` first moves `fut` (this is how the macro can ensure it has ownership of the future), then declares a new variable `fut` of type `Pin<&mut F>` (where `F` is the original `fut`'s type).

Thus, the code following `tokio::pin!(fut)` that uses `fut` manipulates a *pinned reference* to the future, rather than the future value directly. If we try to move `fut`, then we just move the pinned reference. And if we take a mutable reference to `fut`, then we end up with a reference to a pinned reference (`&mut Pin<&mut F>`). This type *does* implement `Future` because:

- `&mut F` [implements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Unpin.html#impl-Unpin-3) `Unpin` even if `F` doesn't implement `Unpin`
- `Pin<&mut F>` [implements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/pin/struct.Pin.html#impl-Unpin) `Unpin` because `&mut F` implements `Unpin`
- `Pin<&mut F>` [implements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/pin/struct.Pin.html#impl-Future) `Future` because `F` implements `Future`
- `&mut Pin<&mut F>` [implements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/future/trait.Future.html#impl-Future) `Future` because `Pin<&mut F>` implements both `Future` and `Unpin`

Answer (score 1):

Edit: this answer is not entirely correct. See the accepted answer.

Surprising requirements about futures can typically be explained by thinking about what the [generated `impl Future` state machine](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/items/functions.html#async-functions) will look like.

In this case, the problem is the following: the state machine generated by the example code will deduce that it needs to hold onto a *reference* to fut in order to await it. Because the state machine also captures the stack, it ends up trying to hold both `fut` and a reference to `fut`. This is a [self-referential struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49860149/how-to-use-the-pin-struct-with-self-referential-structures), and it's problematic because if you were to move the generated future, it would invalidate the self-reference. Solving this problem is the exact [purpose](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/index.html) of pinning. That's why using `tokio::pin!` fixes the compiler error.

Comment: It's rare to see someone answering their own questions. good find!